# how to search keyword without ordering and search keywords which embedded special character without ordering

Tags: python, regex

**update 2**

i edit your suggestion to do 5 cases, near can do all cases, 
but it has extra results, redundant results, how to improve or is there another better solution?

```
case 1
row1 = "search key   $ @ $  words today"
re.findall(r'[(?=k&e&y&w&o&r&d&s)]*[ \$\@]*', row1, re.DOTALL)
['se', '', 'r', '', '', ' ', 'key   $ @ $  ', 'words ', '', 'od', '', 'y', '']

case 2
row1 = "search key      words today"
re.findall(r'[(?=k&e&y&w&o&r&d&s)]*[ \$\@]*', row1, re.DOTALL)
['se', '', 'r', '', '', ' ', 'key      ', 'words ', '', 'od', '', 'y', '']

case 3 need help
row1 = "search key      wrods today"
re.findall(r'[(?=k&e&y&w&o&r&d&s)]*[ \$\@]*', row1, re.DOTALL)
['se', '', 'r', '', '', ' ', 'key      ', 'wrods ', '', 'od', '', 'y', '']

case 4 need help
row1 = "search key  $ @ $     wrods today"
re.findall(r'[(?=k&e&y&w&o&r&d&s)]*[ \$\@]*', row1, re.DOTALL)
['se', '', 'r', '', '', ' ', 'key  $ @ $     ', 'wrods ', '', 'od', '', 'y', '']

case 5 
row1 = "search key      wrds today"
re.findall(r'[(?=k&e&y&w&o&r&d&s)]*[ \$\@]*', row1, re.DOTALL)
['se', '', 'r', '', '', ' ', 'key      ', 'wrds ', '', 'od', '', 'y', '']
```

**udpate 1**

```
case 1 is ok
row1 = "search key   $ @ $  words today"
re.sub(r' ',r'[ \$\@]*', r'key words')
re.findall(re.sub(r' ',r'[ \$\@]*', r'key words'), row1, re.DOTALL)

case 2 is ok
row1 = "search key      words today"
re.sub(r' ',r'[ \$\@]*', r'key words')
re.findall(re.sub(r' ',r'[ \$\@]*', r'key words'), row1, re.DOTALL)

case 3 need help
row1 = "search key      wrods today"
re.sub(r' ',r'[ \$\@]*', r'key words')
re.findall(r'(?=k|e|y|[ \$\@]*|\ |w|o|r|d|s)', row1, re.DOTALL)
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

case 4 need help
row1 = "search key  $ @ $     wrods today"
re.sub(r' ',r'[ \$\@]*', r'key words')
re.findall(r'(?=k|e|y|[ \$\@]*|\ |w|o|r|d|s)', row1, re.DOTALL)
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

A.

since

```
row1 = "search key words today"
searchresult = re.findall(re.sub(r' ', ' *', r'key wrods', flags=re.IGNORECASE), row1, re.DOTALL)
```

r and o are exchanged,

then i search without order with (?=

```
searchresult = re.findall(re.sub(r' ', ' *', r'(?=k)(?=e)(?=y)(?=\ )(?=w)(?=r)(?=o)(?=d)(?=s)', flags=re.IGNORECASE), row1, re.DOTALL)
searchresult
[]
```

return null

how about the case if duplicate character, keyword is "kkey wrods"?

B.

there is error when search keywords from content which embedded special characters in any order include special characters in any order

```
row1 = "search key $ @ $ words today"
re.sub(r' ',r'(?=$*)(?= *)*', r'key words')
re.findall(re.sub(r' ',r'(?=$*)(?=@*)(?= *)*', r'key words'), row1, re.DOTALL)

>>> re.findall(re.sub(r' ',r'(?=$*)(?=@*)(?= *)*', r'key words'), row1, re.DOTALL)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 181, in findall
return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 251, in _compile
raise error, v # invalid expression
```

sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat

just for

```
row1 = "search key     words today"
def easysearch(content, keywords):
    row1 = content
    searchresult = re.findall(re.sub(r' ', ' *', keywords, flags=re.IGNORECASE), row1, re.DOTALL)
    if count_chars(searchresult[0])/count_chars(keywords) > 0.5:
        return searchresult

easysearch(row1, r'key words')
easysearch(row1, r'key wrods')

row1 = "search key   $ @ $  words today"
def easysearch(content, keywords):
    row1 = content
    searchresult = re.findall(re.sub(r' ',r'(?=$*)(?=@*)(?= *)*', keywords), row1, re.DOTALL)
    if count_chars(searchresult[0])/count_chars(keywords) > 0.5:
        return searchresult

easysearch(row1, r'key words')
easysearch(row1, r'key wrods')
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do but `(?=k)(?=e)` can never match because a character cannot be `k` and `e` at the same time.

Comment: i edited to  '(?=k|e|y|[ \$\@]*|\ |w|o|r|d|s)'

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```
row1 = "search key words today"
searchresult = re.findall(re.sub(r' ', ' *', r'key words', flags=re.IGNORECASE), row1, re.DOTALL)
print(searchresult)

row1 = "search key $ @ $ words today"
searchresult = re.findall(re.sub(r' ',r' .*?', r'key words'), row1, re.DOTALL)
print(searchresult)
```

Output is

```
['key words']
['key $ @ $ words']
```

I only just changed your `replacement strings` in the `re.sub()` function and fix the typo `wrods` to `words`

**For the case 3, 4 (Updated)**

you may try this scripts

```
row1 = "search eky        sky key                 wrods today"
print(re.findall(r'(?:(?=k|e|y|[ \$\@]+|w|o|r|d|s).)+', row1, re.DOTALL))

row1 = "search yek key $ @   sky                    $     wrods today"
print(re.findall(r'(?:(?=k|e|y|[ \$\@]+|w|o|r|d|s).)+', row1, re.DOTALL))
```

output is

```
['se', 'r', ' eky        sky key                 wrods ', 'od', 'y']
['se', 'r', ' yek key $ @   sky                    $     wrods ', 'od', 'y']
```

**[P.S]**

What you want to do may be like this

```
row1 = "search eky                       wrods today"
print(re.findall(r'(?:k|e|y)+[ \$\@]+(?:w|o|r|d|s)+', row1, re.DOTALL))

row1 = "search yek $ @                      $     wrods today"
print(re.findall(r'(?:k|e|y)+[ \$\@]+(?:w|o|r|d|s)+', row1, re.DOTALL))
```

output is

```
['eky                       wrods']
['yek $ @                      $     wrods']
```

Comment: how about easysearch(row1, r'key wrods') , o and r exchanged, and see each character without ordering, how to use this to specify each special character '(?=$*)(?=@*)(?= *)*'  custom which special character expected and can be duplicate without ordering

Comment: sorry i missed press your answer edit button, but i canceled edit , it return to previous answer, i updated question, case 3 and case 4 need help

Comment: If you want to specify special character, I recommend you use character class like this, `[\$\@ ]+` .Thus replace script will be change to  `re.sub(r' ', r'[\$\@ ]+', 'key words', flags=re.IGNORECASE)`

Comment: case 3 and case 4 can not be searched by re.findall(re.sub(r' ', r'[\$\@ ]+', 'key words', flags=re.IGNORECASE), row1, re.DOTALL),  how to do to consider case 3 and case 4 too?

Comment: I updated my answer again now. Please check and try it again. Thank you:-)